# Set margin between columns

Tags: html, css

We have 3 columns (someone would want more maybe)

Lets say I want 30px distance between them.

That would mean I need to create 3 different styles :

1. First column  : `margin-right:15px`
2. Center column : `margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;`
3. Last column   : `margin-left:15px;`

Maybe its not quite complicated but its quite no-comfortable, especially when needed for some wordpress etc. where end-user may not have a `HTML` background.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFeFj/).

Is it possible to achieve this in a simple manner ?

Answer (score 1):

You could have

HTML

```
<div class="margin-right">
<div class="margin-left margin-right">
<div class="margin-left">
```

CSS

```
.margin-left { margin-left: 15px }
.margin-right { margin-right: 15px }
```

Comment: Yes, indeed that's still 3 different styles. I would like to set some class maybe, .onethird for them and manage all the rest. With js maybe?

Answer (score 1):

there's an easier solution ( [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFeFj/12/) ) that does not require you to use 2 classes which is:

```
.col-gutter {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.col-gutter:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

you can just set the gutter size to whatever size you need using one single class

**Update ( IE8 )**

if you'd want to support at least IE8 you could use this instead:

```
.col-gutter {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.col-gutter:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: `last-of-type` : This will not be supported by older browsers (IE < 9)

Comment: yep, i didnt. but it would be nice :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kFeFj/25/ what about that. the only 'last last' column has good style. last column in first row doesnt

Comment: i'm not detecting any problems with any column, can you be more explicit ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kFeFj/28/ - now better visible. Look on difference in padding of third columns in first and second row.

Comment: you could remove the last-of-type and make the padding-right apply to the last column. It really depends on your site's layout, because you can have an outter padding giving the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the following method (for 3 column layout):

```
.onethird {
     width: 30%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     float: left;
}
.onethird:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onethird.third {
    float: right;
}
​
```

Just wrap it in a container, and make sure you clear the floats.

Here is an update to your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kFeFj/23/

Answer (score 1):

Try negative margins on a container element

http://jsfiddle.net/5JZGt/ (this demo shows multiple boxes)

Some HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">

    </div>

    <div class="child">

    </div>

    <div class="child">

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.container .child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

You can do away with the `.child` class and just reference the `div` or whatever element you're using.